# Replacing part of a text using jQuery's .replaceWith function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a new masterpage withing sharepoint 2010. One of the placeholders produces the sitename - the page name in a string. When the page is ready the sources shows this for exampe.

```
<h1 class="ribbonmc">
    Devness Squared - Mark Jensen
</h1>
```

Devenss Squared is the site name and Mark Jensen is the page name. I am trying to remove the **sitename** from being displayed and show the page name only using jQuery. This is what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ribbonmc').text(function(i, oldText) {
            return oldText === 'Devness Squared - ' ? '' : oldText;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you simply remove `"Devness Squared -"`?

Comment: it's a class and not an id.. so change `$('#ribbonmc')` to `$('.ribbonmc')`

Comment: `var sitename = 'Devness Squared - '; return oldText.indexOf(sitename) === 0 ? oldText.substr(sitename.length) : oldText`?

Comment: That's the name of the site while in development. When the page loads even after development is finished, I don't want it to display.

Comment: You should work then with the real name then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solution:

```
$(".ribbonmc").text(function(i, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(/^Devness Squared - /, "");
});
```

Non-regex solution:

```
$(".ribbonmc").text(function(i, oldText) {
    var r = "Devness Squared - ";
    return oldText.indexOf(r) === 0 ? oldText.substring(r.length) : oldText;
});
```

Comment: I have another problem with that same code and since you did a great job helping me out with the javascript, I'd come to you again. In the original code I had a span element within the header content. Now that I have created that javascript to edit the text content of the h1 element the span is being erased with that same come. How do I keep the span element?

Comment: @Marcus Does the spam element contain the following text?

Comment: @ VisioN
This is the exact code that I was describing in the problem above.

<h1 class="ribbonmc"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder><span class="arrowmc"></span></h1>

I added your code to help me delete the site name from the text content of the h1 element, however now the span that is in that code is no longer rendering. I have to keep it within the h1 element for positioning purposes.

Comment: did you see my text above?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sitename = 'Devness Squared - ';
    $(".ribbonmc").text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText.indexOf(sitename) === 0    // if it starts with `sitename`
             ? oldText.substring(sitename.length) // t: return everything after it
             : oldText;                           // f: return existing
    });
});
```